# Generating XML file with proper indentation

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I am trying to generate the XML file in python but its not getting indented the out put is coming in straight line.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

name = str(request.POST.get('name'))
top = Element('scenario')
environment = SubElement(top, 'environment')        
cluster = SubElement(top, 'cluster')
cluster.text=name
```

I tried to use pretty parser but its giving me an error as: 'Element' object has no attribute 'read'

```
import xml.dom.minidom

xml_p = xml.dom.minidom.parse(top)
pretty_xml = xml_p.toprettyxml()
```

Is the input given to parser is proper format ? if this is wrong method please suggest another way to indent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly parse `top` which is an `Element()`, you need to make that a string (which is why you should import `tostring`. that you are currently not using), and use `xml.dom.minidom.parseString()` on the result:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

xml_p = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(tostring(top))
pretty_xml = xml_p.toprettyxml()
print(pretty_xml)
```

that gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<scenario>
    <environment/>
    <cluster>xyz</cluster>
</scenario>
```